# Clean data with pandas

Tags: pandas, replace, split, apply

I have multiple files in a folder where I need to rename the headers, split after the first | and remove 'p.'.

The code looks like this

```
path = "/home/kristina/snpeff_analysis/a.a/result/Ann.vcf/TEST_P.G_ann.vcf/PLAY.TEST"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*_G.P.vcf")

#print(all_files)

aa_df = []
for filename in all_files:
  aa_df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
  new_header = {'Gene':'Gene', 'P':'Aminoacids'}
  aa_df.rename(columns=new_header, inplace=True)

  aa_df.to_csv(filename, index=False, sep='\t')

#%%
#split & replace
def get_element(my_list, position):
    return my_list[position]

df = aa_df
for filename in all_files:
   df.Gene.str.split('|').apply(get_element, position=0), df.Aminoacids.str.split('|').apply(get_element, position=0).str.replace('p.','').to_csv(filename, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Ex looking into one file

```
Gene    Aminoacids
gyrA|Rv0007|ppiA|dnaN|recF|Rv0004|gyrB|Rv0008c  p.Ser95Thr|.|.|.|.|.|.|.
rpoB|rpoC|atsD|vapB8|vapC8|Rv0666   p.His445Asp|.|.|.|.|.
Rv1313c|Rv1314c|atpC|Rv1312|murA|ogt|rrs    .|.|.|.|.|.|.
tlyA|ppnK|recN|Rv1697|mctB|mpg|tyrS|lprJ|Rv1691|Rv1692|Rv1693   p.Leu11Leu|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.
```

The  issue that I have is that when running the last part of my script it only outputs the split on the Aminoacids column.

```
Aminoacids
Ser95Thr
His445Asp
.
Leu11Leu
```

But when changing the last command to end with .head instead of .to_csv the ouput in the interactive window looks correct.

```
(0       gyrA
 1       rpoB
 2    Rv1313c
 3       tlyA
 Name: Gene, dtype: object,
 <bound method NDFrame.head of 
 0     Ser95Thr
 1    His445Asp
 2            .
 3     Leu11Leu
 Name: Aminoacids, dtype: object>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you just need to assign your changes to the columns before exporting it.

```
df['Gene'] = df['Gene'].str.split('|').apply(get_element, position=0)
df['Aminoacids'] = df['Aminoacids'].str.split('|').apply(get_element, position=0).str.replace('p.','', regex=True)

df.to_csv(out_path, index=False, sep='\t')
```